# Fix broken BufferedReader String

Tags: java, string, ascii, bufferedreader

I am using BufferedReader in Java to read out strings from a module. If the readout time of the module is >1sek, I receive valid strings that look like the following:

receive string: "2014, 2014, 2014, 2014"

However, when the readout is faster, I receive broken strings from the module like:

receive string: "10��_���2�D"

Does anyone know, how I can handle these strings?

Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                read += line;
                if (reader.ready() == false && !read.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (read.length() > 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you accessing your file simultaneously from different processes?

Comment: Yeah! This function is reading out many times from different processes.

Comment: You must synchronize access in one way or another. There are many possibilities. `synchronize`, file locking, etc.

Comment: can you maybe give me a small hint like a beginning?

Comment: Are all these processes Java processes? Do they run in the same JVM? Or maybe they are just different threads of the same process?

Comment: They are all Java processes in the same jvm